# Babel polyfill transpiles selenium- webdriver's code in a way it can't run on Nashorn

Tags: babeljs, nashorn, babel-polyfill

I'm trying to run selenium-js on Nashorn (please, don't ask why I can't use java version of selenium).

Nashorn (on java8) implements ES5. Current version of selenium-webdriver (3.6.0) written in ES6.

I'm trying to transpile selenium-webdriver using webpack(v4) + babel-polyfill(v6.26.0) + babel-preset-env (1.6.1 with preset es2015).

And then run the code on Nashorn. But get an error

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property "name" of function By(using, value) {
_classCallCheck(this, By);

/** @type {string} */
this.using = using;

/** @type {string} */
this.value = value;}

in webpack:///./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js? at line number 89
at defineProperty (webpack:///./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js?:89)
at defineProperties (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js?:49)
at <anonymous> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js?:49)
at By (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js?:157)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js?:132)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:7024)
at __webpack_require__ (<eval>:20)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js?:37)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:7180)
at __webpack_require__ (<eval>:20)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js?:43)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:7096)
at __webpack_require__ (<eval>:20)
at <anonymous> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js?:33)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js?:264)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:6904)
at __webpack_require__ (<eval>:20)
at <anonymous> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js?:146)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js?:941)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:6832)
at __webpack_require__ (<eval>:20)
at <anonymous> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js?:35)
at <program> (webpack:///./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js?:816)
at <anonymous> (<eval>:6940)
```

Would really appreciate any hint :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this line: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/807b4f560f36a0380d54b03c79c6eaaf45287c73/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/by.js#L201

```
static name(name) {
```

Specifically, in ES5 the `name` property on functions was not defined by the spec, but almost all JS engines included it and had it marked as non-configurable. That means that the line above will throw an exception, because it is trying to assign to `fn.name = ...` to create the static, and that isn't possible.

This works on ES6 environments because the property was changed to be marked configurable, but on older environments I don't believe you have any options other than maybe writing your own Babel plugin to entirely delete that static property. Babel on its own has no way to handle this for you.